# How to express that a musical composition you wrote is your own

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

I am describing a composition that I wrote for an English project that I have to write a paper on.

Would "self-written composition" be correct? Or "self-composed composition", "personal composition" or "my own composition"?

I'd like to know the commonly used term.

Comment: have you considered saying something like "my work" or "my piece"?

Comment: I hadn't noticed that you suggested “*my* [**own composition**](https://www.google.it/search?q=own%20composition&oq=own%20composition&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=%22own%20composition%22&tbm=bks)*” yourself, you can also use that.

Comment: @Mari-LouA This link you have suggested is in Italian and upon clicking it, it gives you a new "dialog box" (lack of a better word) on webpage regarding some privacy concerns which is also in Italian.

Comment: @JonyAgarwal the link doesn't take you to Google books? Even if the search engine is called Google.it, (italy) the results are in English. This is a case where Google thinks it's doing me  a favour. I set the home page for Google.uk, but if I  highlight a word, open the menu tab and search Google, it will *always* open a new tab with Google.it.

Comment: New link with Google.uk, produces these results: [**own composition**](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=%22own+composition%22&start=0)

Comment: @Mari-LouA Good for you that google takes care of your convenience. It does open google with results in English but a pop-up ("dialog box" was just a bad word I used before) which appears on the webpage, is also in Italian ( "Prima di continurae.." , "Avanti" : some words on it). I didn't click anything for the fear of messing something with my google account. But the new link is fine. No pop-ups! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you could say that it is your **original composition**. It is generally used with reference to a piece of music or art.

> An original piece of writing or music was written recently and has not
>   been published or performed before.

http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-cobuild/original%20composition